# TestFlight - User installed app via Public Link and no longer seeing updates

Tags: testflight

I have users that are no longer getting updates from TestFlight. It's saying that the version they are on has expired (as expected) but the new versions aren't showing as available.

I added the users using a public link. I'm wondering how TestFlight tracks installs from public links. Does it track their Apple ID or their iCloud account or what????

My users have their corporate accounts and their private emails and I'm sure they are using a combination of ways they are authenticated. But, it seems to me that TestFlight is somehow not tracking them correctly.